# Oracle timestamp and current_date

Tags: oracle, timestamp

I have this code working:

```
ixdtl.timestamp between
to_date('2015/06/03', 'YYYY/MM/DD')+ INTERVAL '03:0:0.0' HOUR TO SECOND 
  AND to_date('2015/06/03', 'YYYY/MM/DD')+ INTERVAL '1 2:59:59.99' DAY TO SECOND
    AND 
    (
     icrun.RUNDATE BETWEEN to_date('2015/06/03', 'YYYY/MM/DD')
     AND to_date('2015/06/03', 'YYYY/MM/DD')+ INTERVAL '1' DAY 
     )
```

But now, in place of the string '2015/06/03', I need to use the variable current_date so that ixdtl.timestamp is between 3AM yesterday and 3AM today. Also, the rundate needs to be yesterday or today.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CURRENT_DATE` is the current date *and time*. If you want just the date part, use the [`TRUNC`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions209.htm#SQLRF06151) function.

To get 3AM yesterday and 3AM today, it's probably easier to subtract 21 hours from today at midnight for 3AM yesterday, add 3 hours to today at midnight for 3AM Today, and use >= / < instead of `BETWEEN`

```
ixdtl.timestamp >= TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE) - INTERVAL '21' HOUR AND
ixdtl.timestamp < TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE) + INTERVAL '3' HOUR
```

For today and yesterday, look for >= one day ago and < tomorrow.

```
ixdtl.RUNDATE >= TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE) - INTERVAL '1' DAY AND
ixdtl.RUNDATE < TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE) + INTERVAL '1' DAY
```

Put them all together and you get:

```
WHERE ixdtl.timestamp >= TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE) - INTERVAL '21' HOUR
  AND ixdtl.timestamp < TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE) + INTERVAL '3' HOUR
  AND ixdtl.RUNDATE >= TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE) - INTERVAL '1' DAY
  AND ixdtl.RUNDATE < TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE) + INTERVAL '1' DAY
```

Answer (score 1):

Your predicate should read:

```
ixdtl.timestamp
  BETWEEN trunc(CURRENT_DATE) - INTERVAL '21' HOUR
  AND     trunc(CURRENT_DATE) + INTERVAL '3'  HOUR
```